# need help to understand pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am new to pandas and could not understand the below code snippet. Why are we taking a unique timestamp and looping over it, then df[df['measTimeStampRf'] == timestamp]  ?
I understand that this code tries to add time stamp, but what is the use of unique and then comparison?

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
timestamps = df['measTimeStampRf'].unique()
for timestamp in timestamps:
     d = df[df['measTimeStampRf'] == timestamp]       
     d.index = pd.date_range(start=datetime.datetime.now(), freq='1ms', periods=len(d))        
     print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't take only one timestamp, you get **all unique timestamps** like a `set`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'measTimeStampRf': [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3]})
   measTimeStampRf
0                1
1                1
2                2
3                3
4                4
5                4
6                3

>>> df['measTimeStampRf'].unique()
array([1, 2, 3, 4])

>>> df['measTimeStampRf'].value_counts()
1    2
3    2
4    2
2    1
Name: measTimeStampRf, dtype: int64
```

The output of your code is a list of dataframes:

```
timestamps = df['measTimeStampRf'].unique()
for timestamp in timestamps:
     d = df[df['measTimeStampRf'] == timestamp]       
     d.index = pd.date_range(start=datetime.datetime.now(), freq='1ms', periods=len(d))        
     print(d)

# Output
                            measTimeStampRf
2023-03-17 18:14:51.291354                1
2023-03-17 18:14:51.292354                1
                            measTimeStampRf
2023-03-17 18:14:51.293538                2
                            measTimeStampRf
2023-03-17 18:14:51.295483                3
2023-03-17 18:14:51.296483                3
                            measTimeStampRf
2023-03-17 18:14:51.297412                4
2023-03-17 18:14:51.298412                4
```

The equivalent code in Pandas is a `groupby` then an `transform`:

```
def new_ts(sr):
    dti = pd.date_range(start=datetime.datetime.now(), freq='1ms', periods=len(sr))
    return pd.Series(dti, index=sr.index)

df['new_ts'] = df.groupby('measTimeStampRf')['measTimeStampRf'].transform(new_ts)
print(df)

# Output
   measTimeStampRf                     new_ts
0                1 2023-03-17 18:25:12.234216
1                1 2023-03-17 18:25:12.235216
2                2 2023-03-17 18:25:12.235804
3                3 2023-03-17 18:25:12.237127
4                4 2023-03-17 18:25:12.238460
5                4 2023-03-17 18:25:12.239460
6                3 2023-03-17 18:25:12.238127
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with some correction to your code:

You don't need to import *datetime*, as *Pandas* contains its
native function to get *now* time, i.e. *pd.Timestamp.now()*, instead of
*datetime.datetime.now()*.

Invoking *unique* on the timestamp column is needed to get
(no surprise) **unique** timestamps (with no repetitions).

Using comparison to *timestams* is to select the current group of rows
with this tiestamp.

Your code perform actually just a **grouping** by *measTimeStampRf*
and sets the index in each group to consecutive timestamps,
starting from **now** and with the **step** of *1 ms*.

To run your code I created the source DataFrame as:

```
    measTimeStampRf   x   y
0  2023-01-05 20:30  10  11
1  2023-01-05 20:30  12  13
2  2023-01-05 20:30  14  15
3  2023-01-05 20:30  16  17
4  2023-01-06 19:15  20  21
5  2023-01-06 19:15  22  23
6  2023-01-06 19:15  24  25
7  2023-01-06 19:15  26  27
```

As you can see, first 4 rows have *measTimeStampRf* of *2023-01-05 20:30*
and another 4 rows of *2023-01-06 19:15*.

The result of your code is:

```
                             measTimeStampRf   x   y
2023-03-17 17:56:29.311830  2023-01-05 20:30  10  11
2023-03-17 17:56:29.312830  2023-01-05 20:30  12  13
2023-03-17 17:56:29.313830  2023-01-05 20:30  14  15
2023-03-17 17:56:29.314830  2023-01-05 20:30  16  17
                             measTimeStampRf   x   y
2023-03-17 17:56:29.898508  2023-01-06 19:15  20  21
2023-03-17 17:56:29.899508  2023-01-06 19:15  22  23
2023-03-17 17:56:29.900508  2023-01-06 19:15  24  25
2023-03-17 17:56:29.901508  2023-01-06 19:15  26  27
```

Note the leftmost column, i.e. the index.

It starts with *2023-03-17 17:56:29.311830* and then there
are consecutive values increased by 1 ms.

The same pertains to the second group, but this time the
index starts with *2023-03-17 17:56:29.898508*.

Roughly the same result you can get by defining a function to process
each group:

```
def proc(d):
    d.index = pd.date_range(start=pd.Timestamp.now(), freq='1ms', periods=len(d))
    return d
```

and then running:

```
df.groupby('measTimeStampRf', group_keys=False).apply(proc)
```

This time the result is a **single** Dataframe containing:

```
                             measTimeStampRf   x   y
2023-03-17 18:18:06.928383  2023-01-05 20:30  10  11
2023-03-17 18:18:06.929383  2023-01-05 20:30  12  13
2023-03-17 18:18:06.930383  2023-01-05 20:30  14  15
2023-03-17 18:18:06.931383  2023-01-05 20:30  16  17
2023-03-17 18:18:06.928383  2023-01-06 19:15  20  21
2023-03-17 18:18:06.929383  2023-01-06 19:15  22  23
2023-03-17 18:18:06.930383  2023-01-06 19:15  24  25
2023-03-17 18:18:06.931383  2023-01-06 19:15  26  27
```